# How to get current url with filter parametres?

Tags: django, django-urls

I have an url like this :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/uk/events/?title=qwerty&age_filter=1&date_filter=2`
```

How to get current url with filter parametres without language code?

```
`/events/?title=qwerty&age_filter=1&date_filter=2`
```

When I am trying `request.resolver_match.url_name` I am getting `events`.

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
     path('events/', views.events, name='events'),
)
```

Comment: I am very surprised that it gives `/events/` and not `'events'`, since that is the *name* of the `url`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem my bad.

Answer (score 0):

As **@NicoGriffioen** suggested in the comments, you could **get all arguments from the URL** by using `request.GET` which is a dictionary-like object (`django.http.QueryDict`) and then rebuild the url from the url name from `request.resolver_match.url_name` with arguments *without the language code (/uk/)*

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    all_url_args = request.GET

    final_url = request.resolver_match.url_name + "?"
    for name, value in all_url_args.items():
        final_url += name + "=" + value

...
```

For more information on how to use `request.GET` see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET).

Comment: Yeah but I need a path without language code. When I tried to give to the template a variable `my_url = request.get_full_path[4:]` I get ` 
Reverse for '/uk/events/?title=' not found. '/uk/events/?title=' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: @sasha I updated my answer; I understand that is what you need?

Comment: `absolute_url = request.get_full_path()[3:]`
`<a href="{% url "set_language_from_url" user_language="ru" %}?next={{ absolute_url }}">` I get error `Reverse for '/events/?title=' not found. '/events/?title=' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: This method will fail if prefix_default_language is set to false. I would use the url name combined with request.GET.items(), which returns a dictionary of the GET parameters. From these two variables you could restore the original url, without having to dealt with the language prefix.